# C++ Invalid arguments, Candidates are : ".." on Setters from different classes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Getting a weird error which I could not solve.

I have few files, Store.cpp, Store.h (Class Store is defined here), Order.cpp, Order.h (class Order is defined here).

Store.cpp has `#include "Order.h"`.

Inside the class `Order` I have a few setters and getters in the public section, one of them is :

```
void setStatus(const OrderStatus& orderStatus);
```

OrderStatus is an enum.

When I'm trying to use it in Store.cpp with the following line :

```
(*itr).setStatus(ORDER_DONE);
```

I get this error from eclipse :

```
    Invalid arguments '
    Candidates are:
    void setStatus(const enum {order.h:140} &)
    '
```

And this error from GCC :

```
Store.cpp:250:31: error: no matching function for call to
âOrder::setStatus(OrderStatus) constâ 
   Store.cpp:250:31: note: candidate is: 

   order.h:47:7: note: void Order::setStatus(const OrderStatus&)  

   order.h:47:7: note:   no known conversion for implicit âthisâ parameter from âconst Order*â to âOrder*â
```

I really do not know where the const came from (line 250).

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I meant you need a non-const iterator.

Comment: This is what im using..
 for(set<Order>::iterator itr = this->orders.begin() ;
   itr != this->orders.end() ; ++itr)

Comment: @NadavPeled: Sets only allow const-access, otherwise you could totally whack the ordering.

Comment: Oh.
So how can I change what it points to ?
If it points on an Order, how can I change the inner fields of Order, such as order.price ?

Comment: you can either mark the method `const` (and the data member `mutable`), which seems wrong, or `const_cast` the reference, which seems ugly and error-prone. Or, you can use `map` instead of `set`, so you can mutate the value safely.

Comment: You can't. A set is the wrong datastructure for your problem.

Comment: So what you're saying is that the only way to work this way is to remove it from the set, update, and insert again ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::set` is used for storing *immutable value types*. They have to be immutable, because otherwise you can break the ordering constraints when you mutate them.

If you want to associate a mutable *value* with a key (which is immutable for the same reason), use `std::map` instead.

---

The mechanics of it are that:

```
std::set<Order>::iterator iter = ...;
iter->setStatus(ORDER_DONE);
```

doesn't work because `*iter` yields `Order const &` and your method isn't const.

I mentioned in a comment two ways to avoid the problem, but they both do so by subverting const correctness, and I strongly recommend *not* using either of them. But, for completeness:

```
const_cast<Order&>(*iter).setStatus(ORDER_DONE);
```

will make it compile, as would changing the Order class itself:

```
class Order {
    mutable OrderStatus status;
public:
    void setStatus(OrderStatus s) const { status = s; }
};
```

Either of these could also break `std::set`'s ordering invariant if the status is used in the comparison. The first version is saying "just trust me" and sidesteps const correctness completely, while the second explicitly communicates that the status is not a "real" part of the object's state and won't be used for sorting.

Seriously, use the right data structure instead.

Comment: It's homework and set is what we were asked to use..
So the only way to make it work without mutable is removing the element from the set, editing a copy of it, and insertin ?

Comment: I suspect that's the only sane way, yes. If you're iterating over the set modifying _everything_, you could just `transform` the input set into an output set, though.

Answer (score 2):

In order to change elements of a `set`, you must remove the element to a local copy, modify it there, then insert it back in,

`set`s are fragile and assume elements do not change their order while within the container, which is why access to the elements is `const`.